# Matlab Boxplot- change group order on labels

Tags: matlab, boxplot, label

I'd like to change the vertical order of my x-axis labels on a boxplot with two groups.  The current groupings of the boxplots should not change.  Specifically, the labels that are currently immediately below the x-axis need to move down one line, while the bottom-most line of x-axis labels need to move up a line.

Here is the relevant MATLAB Code I'm currently using:

```
Err=horzcat(Err1,Err2,Err3); %size(Err)= 15x12
method = repmat({'Regression' 'Regress Origin'  'RoM CF' 'MoR CF',},1,3);
data = [repmat({'RoM'},1,4),repmat({'MoR'},1,4),repmat({'Geo'},1,4)];
h=figure;
boxplot(Err,{method,data},'colors',repmat('kkk',1,4),'labelverbosity','minor');
set(findobj(get(h(1), 'parent'), 'type', 'text'), 'fontsize', 10);
```

Comment: Silly question: what if you just invert 'method' and 'data' in your call to boxplot? Is it too jam packed?

Comment: @Benoit_11 That was the first thing I tried.  Inverting 'method' and 'data' changes the groups.  I have four groups of three.  The suggested inversion creates three groups of four, but the label levels are then correct.  Perhaps I need to do something in addition to your suggestion..?  I might just add the labels manually with a text box.  Thanks.

Comment: mhh yes indeed. Can you post a small example runnable with  your data; i.e. post Err? thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11 Change the first line of code in my post to Err=normrnd(0,1,[15,12]);

Comment: mhh yep I'm afraid you will have to use text annotations indeed; in the doc it says that boxplot uses text annotations for the x labels so you might as well make them yourself. Sorry! Do you need help with that?

Comment: @Benoit_11 Thank you for looking into this.  I think I can handle this using the textbox tool.

Comment: ok good then good luck!